# Sum column based on conditions in another column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, which contains two columns, `Time` and `Response`

```
df = cbind.data.frame(
                     Time = c(1, 1.2, 1.9, 2.2, 2.9, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.6, 3.9, 4, 5.1, 5.99), 
                     Response = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.3, 6, 11, 13)
                     )
```

I want to transform it  by summing the Response within the same minute (Time) . [1-2), [2-3), [3-4), [4-5), and [5 and above].

The expected data frame will be

```
dfe = cbind.data.frame(
                      time.range = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                      Response = c(3, 5, 19.4, 6, 24)
                      )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `floor` to group it for every minute

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(minute = floor(Time)) %>%
  summarise(Response = sum(Response))

#   minute Response
#    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1      1      3  
#2      2      5  
#3      3     20.4
#4      4      6  
#5      5     24
```

---

Using `aggregate` in base R

```
aggregate(Response~floor(Time), df, sum)
```

Also with `tapply`

```
tapply(df$Response, floor(df$Time), sum)
```

---

And for completion `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,sum(Response), by = floor(Time)]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowsum` from `base R`

```
rowsum(df$Response, as.integer(df$Time))
#   [,1]
#1  3.0
#2  5.0
#3 20.4
#4  6.0
#5 24.0
```